# How to iterate through a DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to iterate through a `DataTable`. I have a column there named `ImagePath`.

When I am using `DataReader` I do it this way:

```
SqlDataReader dr = null;
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (dr.Read())
{
    TextBox1.Text = dr["ImagePath"].ToString();
}
```

How can I achieve the same thing using `DataTable`?

Comment: dr.Read() reads row by row from the network buffer, not row by row from the database.There is only one fetch from the database. Hence reading from a datatable is not going offer any performance gain.

Answer (score 373, accepted):

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

adapter.Fill(dt);

foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    TextBox1.Text = row["ImagePath"].ToString();
}
```

...assumes the connection is open and the command is set up properly. I also didn't check the syntax, but it should give you the idea.

Comment: suppose someone is looking a `linq` solution and wondering where is `(cmd)` in the above solution?

Comment: @RehanKhan - `cmd` would be the SQL Command to execute. If you're using LINQ, you'd write your LINQ Query and get your results that way.

Comment: Why not use for loop instead of foreach? row is only being used once, so for loop would give better performance?

Answer (score 41):

```
foreach (DataRow row in myDataTable.Rows)
{
   Console.WriteLine(row["ImagePath"]);
}
```

I am writing this from memory.
Hope this gives you enough hint to understand the object model.

`DataTable` -> `DataRowCollection` -> `DataRow` (which one can use & look for column contents for that row, either using columnName or ordinal).

-> = contains.

Answer (score 23):

You can also use linq extensions for DataSets:

```
var imagePaths = dt.AsEnumerble().Select(r => r.Field<string>("ImagePath");
foreach(string imgPath in imagePaths)
{
    TextBox1.Text = imgPath;
}
```

Comment: Please note that to have `AsEnumerable()` for `DataTable` you need to have `System.Data.DataSetExtensions` be added as a dependency.

Comment: Not available in .Net Core see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45900952/convert-datatable-to-ienumerablet-in-asp-net-core-2-0

Answer (score 14):

There are already nice solution has been given. The below code can help others to query over datatable and get the value of each row of the datatable for the ImagePath column.

```
  for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
  {
       var theUrl = dataTable.Rows[i]["ImagePath"].ToString();
  }
```

Comment: you saved my day. :) thank you so much for sharing this very simple code of yours. ^_^

Answer (score 6):

The above examples are quite helpful. But, if we want to check if a particular row is having a particular value or not. If yes then delete and break and in case of no value found straight throw error. Below code works:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dtData.Rows)
        {
            if (row["Column_name"].ToString() == txtBox.Text)
            {
                // Getting the sequence number from the textbox.
                string strName1 = txtRowDeletion.Text;

                // Creating the SqlCommand object to access the stored procedure
                // used to get the data for the grid.
                string strDeleteData = "Sp_name";
                SqlCommand cmdDeleteData = new SqlCommand(strDeleteData, conn);
                cmdDeleteData.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                // Running the query.
                conn.Open();
                cmdDeleteData.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();

                GetData();

                dtData = (DataTable)Session["GetData"];
                BindGrid(dtData);

                lblMsgForDeletion.Text = "The row successfully deleted !!" + txtRowDeletion.Text;
                txtRowDeletion.Text = "";
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                lblMsgForDeletion.Text = "The row is not present ";
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is an insane way to accomplish deleteing rows!! Just emit a single  TSQL delete statement!

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1){ var a = row.Cells[4].Value.ToString(); }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some _context_, explaining _how_ it works and _when_ to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.