# How to get data from dataset without linq?

Tags: c#, .net-2.0, oledb

Is there a possibility to get data from dataset without using LINQ? I use VS 2005 and .net 2.0.

```
            string connectionString = String.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};", _DbFile);

            using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
            {
                try
                {
                    con.Open();

                    _Data = new DataSet();

                    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM a", con);
                    adapter.Fill(_Data, "a");

                    adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM b", con);
                    adapter.Fill(_Data, "b");

                    // get data...
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }
```

Comment: This is not clear what you're trying to do. Are you trying to populate something with the data? Get a specific cell? Aggregate it? Do something else?

Comment: ok, I want to get a list of some values joining tables a and b. Something like <select a.ID from a join b on a.ID=b.a_ID where b.Name="foo">

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use row and column indexes to reach the cell value. You can also use column names instead of index.

```
 if(_Data.Tables.Count > 0 && _Data.Rows.Count > 0 && _Data.Columns.Count > 0)
 {
        string row0col0Data = _Data.Tables[0].Rows[0].Cols[0].ToString();
 }
```

Comment: Well, I have to iterate the rows to compare cell values when using a where statement...

Comment: You can use for loop http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1774498/how-to-iterate-through-a-datatable

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you're looking for something like Adil has suggested, or use table name and column names:

```
_Data.Tbales["a"].Rows[i]["columnName"]
```