# Create Json string by looping over DataTable rows

Tags: c#, sql, json, loops, foreach

I need to create a Json string from a SQL query.  I have some basic code working with static data.  Now I need to figure out how to loop over the DataTable rows and create my list of strings.

```
string sql = "SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName";

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mydb"].ToString());
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
adapter.Fill(dt);


return Json(new
{
    sEcho = param.sEcho,
    iTotalRecords = dt.Rows.Count,
    iTotalDisplayRecords = dt.Rows.Count,
    aaData = new List<string[]>() {
        new string[] {"4806", "Kenneth", "Sheffield"},
        new string[] {"3063", "Michael", "Harrison"},
        new string[] {"4000", "Jose", "Penalosa"}
    }
},
```

Comment: Looks like you want to do something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1774498/how-to-iterate-through-a-datatable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following article, [Producing JSON Documents from SQL Server queries via TSQL](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/producing-json-documents-from-sql-server-queries-via-tsql/), covers this process within SQL Server.

Assuming that you have a populated `DataTable` object, you could iterate through the table's rows (i.e., `DataRow` objects) as follows:

```
var list = new List<string[]>();

foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    // This code sample could be collapsed further, but is not for this example.
    // Additionally, this sample does not include any validation or error-checking.
    string id = row["ID"].ToString();
    string firstName = row["FirstName"].ToString();
    string lastName = row["LastName"].ToString();
    // Validation & error-checking could go here before executing the Add() method.
    list.Add(new string[] {id, firstName, lastName});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pull the data out like this:

```
foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    var id = row["ID"].ToString();
    var fname = row["FirstName"].ToString();
    var lname = row["LastName"].ToString();
}
```