# C# console application call a stored procedure and output file in csv file

Tags: c#, csv, stored-procedures, console, output

I am trying to build a console application in c#, and the result I would like to put it into a csv file.

When I execute the code nothing happens. When I trying to debug I am having trouble to identify what can be happening.

Here's is the console code

```
namespace ConsoleOutputFile
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString))
                {
                    var outCsvFile = @"C:\test\result.csv";
                    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
                    sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    sqlCmd.Connection = conn;
                    sqlCmd.CommandText = "ExportTasks";

                    conn.Open();

                    DataSet dsData = new DataSet();
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);


                    File.WriteAllText(outCsvFile, dt.Columns[0].ToString());

                    da.Fill(dsData);
                    conn.Close();
                }

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my app.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 

    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/></startup>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add connectionString="Server=TestServer;database=test;user=sa;pwd=test" name="Connection"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: well that makes sense, you're eating the exception.  A good first step in debugging is to read the error.  Try `catch(Exception e) { Console.WriteLine(e.Message); }` as your catch.  Or just use a break point

Comment: What database server are you using? MySQL? If so, I think the `user` part is wrong, as MySQL uses `Uid` instead of `user`.

Comment: I am using SQL server 2008

Comment: You are writing to file before you call da.Fill(dsData). Fill the datatable before writing to the file:

Answer (score 1):

You are dumping an empty datatable. At no point did you populate the datatable (dt). Do something like this:

```
DataSet dsData = new DataSet();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
da.Fill(dsData);
File.WriteAllText(outCsvFile, dsData.Tables[0].Columns[0].ToString());
```

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Hi I took your advice but I am still getting an empty file I have putted your suggestion just after the conn.Open();

Comment: Does your procedure work in SQL Server Management Studio? You need to verify that your procedure returns data otherwise the code I suggested should work just fine. I would prefer using a datareader:
                SqlDataReader reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
                using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(outCsvFile))
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                        file.WriteLine(reader[0].ToString());
                }

Comment: Hi, its kind of work. The stored procedure return me data when using yours but it only return me one column. According to the debug its has 24 columns

Comment: According to the stored procedure, I need to pass some parameters so I ha to add sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue. I need to return those parameters into the columns in questions

Comment: Hi, I ended up having it work, I just added reader[0].ToString() + ',' + reader[1].ToString() ....and so on until I reach the total of my columns. The only thing missing now its to add the header to each column, any idea?

Comment: string headers = string.Empty;
                for (int i = 0; i <  dr.Table.Columns.Count; i++)
                    headers += dr.Table.Columns[i].ColumnName + ",";

Answer (score 0):

Start here: if an exception is being thrown inside that `try`, you catch it but don't do anything with it.  Put something in there that would help with your debugging.  Exceptions have a property, `Message`, so you can write `Message` to the console:

```
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
```

Whoever is throwing the exception, they will likely provide a helpful message along with it.  Writing it to the Console will help your efforts.

Next, add a breakpoint to your solution.  When you run it, the debugger will stop at the breakpoint.  Use `F10` to step through one line at a time.  This will also help you track down what is going wrong.  More on that [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ktf38f66%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Comment: Hi, I was able to display a message and its says "cannot find column 0"

Answer (score 0):

You initialize but never fill you datatable. Consider using a DataReader to execute the query then load the datatable with the results

```
SqlDataReader dr = dalMgr.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
dt.Load(dr);
```

or nix the datatable altogether and

```
string output = dr["column_name"].ToString();
```

Comment: Hi tried the first option but its says dalMgr does not exist in the current context

Comment: SqlDataReader dr = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: I am executing the console and I get the csv file but it only contain one work "Task" and its does not contain anything else. I am using something wrong?

Comment: What is returned in your result set? Which method did you end up using? Please supply a bit more detail.

Comment: Hi, sorry if I did not give any more details. I used the first method and I insert it just before of  File.WriteAllText... When I do the debug its show me the count of my columns but the file does not contain anything (only one row)

Comment: hmm, not sure I completely follow but it sounds like you either need to iterate through the datatable or loop through the datareader. This link contains examples of both http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1774498/how-to-iterate-through-a-datatable