# C# - How To Loop Through A Table To Update Each Row MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm working on a project where I have to update a table in MySql by looping through it and update every row (one by one) in C#. **NOTE:** I have to update the value's of only one column in my table.

Now, I know this question has been asked (many times) before but after spending a lot of time searching around the internet I haven't found a solution for my problem.

**More Explanation:**

So I already know a few things that are necessary to make this work:

- I know how to establish a (working) SSH connection.
- I know how to establish a (working) MySql connection to my database.
- I know how to run/execute a `SELECT` and `UPDATE` Query/Command in C#.

So the only thing that I need to make this whole thing work, is the loop itself.

Now, during my research I came across some answers that suggested using a `Reader`. I don't know if this is what I need and (if yes) how to use it correctly.

Below is the code that I have so far (for establishing the connections and executing query's).

**My Code:**

```
class ReaderDemo1
{
    public static void Update()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("[Core] Opening Connection To Database...");
        Database.openStockConn(Settings.databaseName, Settings.databaseUsername, Settings.databasePassword, Settings.sshHost, Settings.sshUsername, Settings.sshPassword);

        if (Database.stockConn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            Database.openStockConn(Settings.databaseName, Settings.databaseUsername, Settings.databasePassword, Settings.sshHost, Settings.sshUsername, Settings.sshPassword);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("[Core] database connection is now open!\n");

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT value FROM catalog_product_entity_decimal", Database.stockConn);
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("[Price] Updating Prices...");

            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE catalog_product_entity_decimal SET value= 1112 WHERE value_id= 4063", Database.stockConn);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            Console.WriteLine("[Price] Prices Have Been Updated!");                
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Updating Failed!");
        }
        finally
        {
            if (Database.stockConn != null)
            {
                Database.stockConn.Close();
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Just to give some extra context:

- `Database.cs` is where I create the connections (`SSH` and `MySql`)
- `Settings.cs` is where I have all the Login data for the `SSH` and `MySql` connections.

If you guys would want to know, I have already attempted a few things myself regarding the loop but (as I already mentioned) these attempts weren't successful.

**My Attempt With Reader:**

```
using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
     var indexOfValue = reader.GetOrdinal("value");

     while (reader.Read())
     {
          var price1 = reader.GetValue(indexOfValue);

           Console.WriteLine("Executing Update Command...");

           MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE catalog_product_entity_decimal SET value= 1222 WHERE entity_id= 759 AND entity_id= 839 AND entity_id= 881", con);
           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

           Console.WriteLine("Update Command Executed!"); 
    }
}
```

As said, the code above didn't work how I wanted it to work (probably because it isn't actually doing anything now). Just to let you guys know, I am not stuck at an error. I'm just stuck on how to do this.

I hope one of you guys can help me with this or point me in the rigth direction and if you think that my question is a duplicate of another one, just tell me and I will look into it! :) Thanks in advance.

Kind regards,

LKS

**EDIT:**

In case you guys wanted to know, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMRYt.png) is what my table looks like.
The table contains about 5600 rows, so these are just the top rows.

Comment: If you want to be helped, at least tell us what is the error message.

Comment: @Steve I'm not receiving an error, I simple don't know how I can loop through my table. With or without the `Reader`.

Comment: @Steve so I'm not asking you guys to solve an error message i'm getting but I'm asking you guys how I can loop through my table. :)

Comment: you mean looping like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/1774515/9055793

Comment: You _think_ the solution is a loop. But what would be better? To submit 3 (or 3000) update statements? Or to instead run `UPDATE catalog_product_entity_decimal SET value= 1222 WHERE entity_id IN (759 , 839 , 881)`?

Comment: Is an Orm a no-no ?

Comment: @DragandDrop I'm sorry but I am not sure what you mean by an Orm?

Comment: @LinkerKnieSchijf - Object-Relation-Mapper, which in C# is going to be EntityFramework.  Really, though, doing this per-row is going to be slower and less sure than performing a batch update; ideally you upload all the rows to a staging table (assuming the values will be different for each row), then run a single `UPDATE` statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Frederiks answer, the thing that you are trying to do now is Looping over an table and execute the same Query over and over again.

Even if you manage to get your code working it would be very slow (because you have about 5600 rows to update).

So my suggestion is that you create an new table with the new value's in it (so the one's you wanted to have after your loop). Then just run a single update command to update your old table with values from your new table.

This option probably takes a few seconds and it will be done, so its much faster! :)

The Query you need should look something like this:

```
    UPDATE old_table
    INNER JOIN  new_table 
    USING (column) --> // if you want to update a specific column
```

**EDIT:**

In addition/ update to my answer, this is how you can update your table more accurate:

```
UPDATE old_table
   INNER JOIN new_table ON old_table.value_id = new_table.value_id  // Use this to set your columns with unique values's
   SET old_table.value = new_table.value // For the column with the value's you want to update
```

So, in the above code you update your `old_table` with the value's from your `new_table`. In this example you only update the value's from only one column (which you wanted).

You can expand the query for a different result.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Will definitely look into this!

Comment: This worked like a charm! Thank you very much for answering! :D

Comment: @LinkerKnieSchijf no problemo! :)

Answer (score 2):

I cannot think of any reason that you would want to read one line at a time and write one line at a time in a loop, but this is how you could do it.

Use one SqlCommand to read and a separate SqlCommand to update.  Change the parameters in the loop for each update.

```
public static void Update()
{
    Database.openStockConn(Settings.databaseName, Settings.databaseUsername, Settings.databasePassword, Settings.sshHost, Settings.sshUsername, Settings.sshPassword);

    if (Database.stockConn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        Database.openStockConn(Settings.databaseName, Settings.databaseUsername, Settings.databasePassword, Settings.sshHost, Settings.sshUsername, Settings.sshPassword);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("[Core] database connection is now open!\n");

    MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand("SELECT value FROM catalog_product_entity_decimal", Database.stockConn);
    MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE catalog_product_entity_decimal SET value= 1112 WHERE value_id= 4063", Database.stockConn);


    try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("[Price] Updating Prices...");

        using (var reader = cmd1.ExecuteReader())
        {
            var indexOfValue = reader.GetOrdinal("value");

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var price1 = reader.GetValue(indexOfValue);

                Console.WriteLine("Executing Update Command...");

                cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

                Console.WriteLine("Update Command Executed!");
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Updating Failed!");
    }
    finally
    {
        if (Database.stockConn != null)
        {
            Database.stockConn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering! I've tried your code but now it keeps saying that `"There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first"`. It's probably just a `.Close();` that I have to put somewhere but I don't know where to put it ( I've tried but then it says that It doesn't work because the `Reader` is closed, I probably put it in a/the wrong spot), so a little more help would be nice haha

Comment: You could use two separate connections.  Put them in stacked using blocks, and you will not need to worry about closing them.

Comment: I still see no reason why you want to read one line at a time or update one line at a time.  Why not perform this in one update command?

Answer (score 2):

SQL is set based, which means that there is almost always a better approach then looping over a table.
That is also the case with your problem.  You want to avoid looping over an entire table to update record-by-record, since this is terribly slow.

It is not obvious to me on what you're trying to achieve, since your code sample loops over a table and then inside your loop, you execute the same statement over and over again, but you're always updating the exact same records ?

If you want to update records in a table with information coming from another table, you might want to have a look at the UPDATE statement together with the JOIN clause as explained [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-update-join/).

Comment: Thanks for answering! Updating value's in a table with value's coming from another table is indeed very interesting, will definitely look into this!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this change , by having the count of rows and then updating the records.

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT count(*) FROM catalog_product_entity_decimal", Database.stockConn);
    try
    {
        var reader = cmd .ExecuteReader();
        if(reader.Read()){
            var totalRows=reader.GetInt32(0);
            Console.WriteLine("[Price] Updating Prices...");

              while(totalRows-->0){
                    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE catalog_product_entity_decimal SET value= 1112 WHERE value_id= 4063", Database.stockConn);
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

               }
            Console.WriteLine("[Price] Prices Have Been Updated!");   
        }             
    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Updating Failed!");
    }
    finally
    {
        if (Database.stockConn != null)
        {
            Database.stockConn.Close();
        }
    }
```