# how to convert single column to multiple columns datatable c#

Tags: c#

i have DataTable which has only one column, how do I convert it to four columns.

my DataTable looks like below

```
Column1
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

and I want to convert it as showing below

```
Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4
1       2       3       4
5       6       7       8
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @UsmanAli - Then please try something. If it doesn't work then please post your code so that we can help.

Comment: @Enigmativity, i have no idea where to start from

Comment: Do you need it to be programmaticaly generated or you know already which values will reside in the columns?. Please give some context of your problem: how do you represent the data, how do you populate the column, etc. As the other SO fellows suggested, please give a try before (otherwise people would need to make different assumptions - generally this is a bad idea)

Comment: yes, you can write down the requirement on the paper, define steps to follow and go throw it. [Look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1774498/how-to-iterate-through-a-datatable)

Comment: @UsmanAli A quick online search turned up: [Adding columns to a DataTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataset-datatable-dataview/adding-columns-to-a-datatable) and [deleting rows from a datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5648339/deleting-specific-rows-from-datatable). Try something and then come back if you get stuck!

Comment: @UsmanAli - Sure you know where to start. Start by declaring a `DataTable` and populating it - show us that code. Declare a second `DataTable` and populate that with your desired output. Give us that too. That gives us something to test against. Then just try to convert it - even by copy field by field. You can surely do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
            dt1.Columns.Add("Column1", typeof(int));
            dt1.Rows.Add(1);
            dt1.Rows.Add(2);
            dt1.Rows.Add(3);
            dt1.Rows.Add(4);
            dt1.Rows.Add(5);
            dt1.Rows.Add(6);
            dt1.Rows.Add(7);
            dt1.Rows.Add(8);

            DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
            dt2.Columns.Add("Column1", typeof(int));
            dt2.Columns.Add("Column2", typeof(int));
            dt2.Columns.Add("Column3", typeof(int));
            dt2.Columns.Add("Column4", typeof(int));


            for (int i = 0; i < dt1.Rows.Count; i += 4)
            {
                dt2.Rows.Add(new object[] { dt1.Rows[i].Field<int>("Column1"), dt1.Rows[i + 1].Field<int>("Column1"), dt1.Rows[i + 2].Field<int>("Column1"), dt1.Rows[i + 3].Field<int>("Column1") });
            }

        }
    }
}
```