# C# get many rows in one line

Tags: c#, sql-server

in C# I'm currently getting some data from SQL, my query returns me only one column due to my select (see code below) but in some case, it could be possible that I have more than one row, so I'd like to know if is there a way to return these row in only one line of text?

Here my current code:

```
  public bool getDBValue(string m_strValue, string m_strFilter, string m_strDBTable, out DataSet m_objDs, out string m_strError)

 try
 {
    using (SqlConnection oConn = new SqlConnection(getConnectionString()))
    {
       oConn.Open();
       SqlDataAdapter l_objAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("Select [" + m_strValue + "] FROM "+ m_strDBTable+" Where ProjectUID =" + "'" + m_strFilter + "'", oConn);
       m_objDs = new DataSet();
       l_objAdapter.Fill(m_objDs);
    }
    return (true);
 }
 catch (Exception e)
 {
    m_strError = e.Message;
    return (false);
 }
```

Because for the moment, I used my data with with line:

```
string value = l_objDs.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ColumnName"].ToString();
```

but as I could have many values, it returns only one values. So any idea of how could I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: You can't have many values in a single row field. If you want to retrieve the values from other rows, use a different row index.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to iterate through a DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1774498/how-to-iterate-through-a-datatable)

Comment: You can l_objAdapter.Fill() method and just keep on adding the results of each query.  As long as you only create the DataSet once.  So you can do following : if(m_objDs == null) m_objDs = new DataSet();  then all the queries will get appended to one DataSet.

Comment: You want many rows or only one row data with the matching value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `foreach` to loop through all rows:

```
string value = "";
foreach (DataRow row in m_objDs.Tables[0].Rows)
  value += row["ColumnName"];
```

Answer (score 2):

No it is not possible since you have taking value at Row[0] of Table[0] so you will get value of first row of your first Table.

string value = l_objDs.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ColumnName"].ToString();

i would rather suggest you to iterate over table rows and add it to a StringBuilder and then assign it to the string value.

Something like Below.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (DataRow dr in l_objDs.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            sb.Append(dr["ColumnName"]);
        }
 string value= sb.ToString();
```

Hope This Helps!