# DataGridView Generating Error When AllowUserToAddRows is true

Tags: c#, ms-access, exception, datagridview, boolean

I have ms-access database application in C#. The tables data is binded to DataGridView in C#. I have added a new **CheckBox** Field named `Check` in my Table.

When `AllowUserToAddRows` is set to `false`. On loading of DGV no error is generated.

When `AllowUserToAddRows` is set to `True`. On loading of DGV error is generated. Error is under:-

[image]

The DGV is in child form. Its code is given below.

```
public partial class frmStudents : Form
{
    // Declaration
    private DataTable dTable;
    public frmStudents()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        
    }

    private void frmStudents_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadTheme();

        // Show Students
        StudentsLoadDGV();
    }
    private void LoadTheme()
    {
        //foreach (Control btns in this.Controls)  Check all controls in Form
        foreach(Button btns in this.Controls.OfType<Button>())      // Check only buttons in Form
        {
            if (btns.GetType() == typeof(Button))
            {
                Button btn = (Button)btns;
                btn.BackColor = ThemeColor.PrimaryColor;
                btn.ForeColor = Color.White;
                btn.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = ThemeColor.SecondaryColor;
            }
        }
    }
    // Getting data from Database to DataTable
    private DataTable StudentsDTable()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(DatabaseObjects.ConnectionString))
        {
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT s.Check, " +
            "DCount("RollNo","students","RollNo <=" & [RollNo]) AS SrNo, s.RollNo, s.SName, "+ 
            "s.FName, s.DOB, c.Class, s.[Section], s.Picture FROM students AS s LEFT JOIN classes "+ 
            "AS c ON s.ClassID = c.ClassID ORDER BY s.RollNo", conn);
            conn.Open();
            dt.Load(command.ExecuteReader());
        }
        return dt;
    }

    // Loading DataTable into DataGridView
    private void StudentsLoadDGV()
    {
        dTable = StudentsDTable();
        dgvDisplay.DataSource = dTable;
                    // Change Column Headings
        dgvDisplay.Columns["SrNo"].HeaderText = "Sr No";
        dgvDisplay.Columns["RollNo"].HeaderText = "Roll No";
        dgvDisplay.Columns["SName"].HeaderText = "Student Name";
        dgvDisplay.Columns["FName"].HeaderText = "Father Name";
        dgvDisplay.Columns["DOB"].HeaderText = "Date of Birth";
        //dgvDisplay.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
        
    }

    private void btnNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult result;
        using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(DatabaseObjects.ConnectionString))
        {
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("select * from Classes", conn);
            conn.Open(); 
            dTable = new DataTable();
            dTable.Load(command.ExecuteReader());
            frmStudentProfile form = new frmStudentProfile(dTable, "New");
            result = form.ShowDialog();
        }
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            StudentsLoadDGV();
    }

    private void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!ValidSelection())
            return;

        DialogResult result;
        // Get the index of the row of selected cell, then get the RollNo from the clicked row and pass it to the command
        int index  = dgvDisplay.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
        var selectedRollNo = dgvDisplay.Rows[index].Cells["RollNo"].Value;
        using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(DatabaseObjects.ConnectionString))
        {
            string query = "select s.RollNo, s.SName, s.FName, s.DOB, c.Class, c.ClassID, s.[Section], s.Picture from Classes as c " +
                "left outer join (select * from Students where RollNo = @RollNo) as s on s.ClassID = c.ClassID";
            using(OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, conn))
            {
                command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("RollNo", selectedRollNo));
                dTable = new DataTable();
                conn.Open();
                dTable.Load(command.ExecuteReader());
                frmStudentProfile form = new frmStudentProfile(dTable, "default");
                result = form.ShowDialog();
            }
        }
        if(result == DialogResult.OK)
            StudentsLoadDGV();
    }

    private void dgvDisplay_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!ValidSelection())
            return;
        
        DialogResult result;
        // Get row number that was clicked
        var index = e.RowIndex;
        // get the RollNo from the clicked row and pass it to the command
        var selectedRollNo = dgvDisplay.Rows[index].Cells["RollNo"].Value;
        using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(DatabaseObjects.ConnectionString))
        {
            string query = "select s.RollNo, s.SName, s.FName, s.DOB, c.Class, c.ClassID, s.[Section], s.Picture from Classes as c " +
                "left outer join (select * from Students where RollNo = @RollNo) as s on s.ClassID = c.ClassID";
            using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, conn))
            {
                command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("RollNo", selectedRollNo));
                dTable = new DataTable();
                conn.Open();
                dTable.Load(command.ExecuteReader());
                frmStudentProfile form = new frmStudentProfile(dTable, "default");
                result = form.ShowDialog();
            }
        }
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            StudentsLoadDGV();
    }

    private bool ValidSelection()
    {
        bool isValid = true;
        string errorMsg = "";
        if (dgvDisplay.SelectedRows.Count > 1 )
        {
            errorMsg += "- Select one Record which you want to Edit.";
            isValid = false;
        }
        else if((dgvDisplay.SelectedCells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>().Select(c => c.RowIndex).Distinct().Count() > 1))
        {
            errorMsg += "- Select Cells of one Record which you want to Edit.";
            isValid = false;
        }
        
        if(!isValid)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(errorMsg, "Invalid Selection", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        return isValid;
    }
}
```

How could i remove the above said error??

Comment: My first guess is that your checkbox field in Access contains text data since the error says "value '' cannot be converted to boolean", which is a true statement by the way. It has been a long time since I worked with Access, but make sure that the checkbox field has boolean value for every record in the table.

Comment: Is your 'check' field actually a Yes/No type? Yes/No type has either 0 or -1, cannot be Null.

Comment: I forgot to mention this earlier. As I recall from my earlier days messing with Access, it is possible to make checkbox fields triple state, which means it is not Boolean.

Comment: @David.Warwick i have checked my query in Ms-Access, all the records have `No` checkbox value.

Comment: @June7  `Check` field is Yes/No type.

Comment: Unless something has changed since Access 2010, a yes/no field cannot be triple state.  A yes/no field must have value of 0 or -1. An unbound checkbox control can have triple state.

Comment: What is displayed in the DGV check field when AllowUserToAddRows is false? Can you take a screen shot of the populated DGV? Have you tried explicitly making the DGV Yes No field a boolean type before assigning the datasource? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.datatype?view=netframework-4.6.1

Comment: what is meant by unbound checkbox control? @June7

Comment: When `AllowUserToAddRows` is `false`. No error is generated. Screenshot is added. @David.Warwick

Comment: Thanks for the screen shots. Did you check out the link I sent you and try defining the data table manually? I suggest defining it manually, then filling it, and then attach it to the datagrid datasource.

Comment: An unbound checkbox control would be a checkbox not connected to data on a form.

Comment: My perspective is from view of an Access form so I guess not relevant to your use of C# coding.

Comment: I have manually define the Data Type for checkbox field after loading the `DataTable`. But still same error. @David.Warwick

Comment: @MuhammadRizwan, ok, I suggest you iterate through the datatable after you fill it and look at the value of the checkbox column to see what it is. Please let me know the value. It should not be a string. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1774498/how-to-iterate-through-a-datatable

Comment: @David.Warwick i iterate through datatable. I showed the value of checkbox in MessageBox.show. I have 11 records in table. The iteration shows 11 times `false` value in MessageBox. Then the above said error is shown and new row is added at the end

Comment: This problem will probably go away if you use strongly typed datasets. There is actually a lot of your code that can be replaced by code that visual studio writes, I think .. and it does a better job than humans do. Upload your code and db somewhere and give a link to it. I'll take a look at what can be done. I suspect this could be caused by data type mismatched or solved by default values specification

Comment: Why do you need to have "allowusertoaddrows" as true? You have a "New" button that opens a dialog tat adds records to the DB. Why do you want to allow users to type new records straight into the grid?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is a client side thing; the datatable connected to the students grid has a "Check" column that is boolean, but doesn't have a default value set. This is a problem if a datagrid tries to add a new row at the bottom of the grid. The datagrid, bound to the datatable, will call datatable.NewRow() to obtain a new row with suggested default values for showing at the bottom of the grid. If the user types into this row then navigates elsewhere the row will be committed to the datatable. Because your Check column lacks a default it will be Null on the detached row returned by NewRow, and DataGridView's comboboxcolumn will choke on it because it needs a true or false, rather than a null

Putting this line of code in your `StudentDTable` method, after you load the table will stop the error appearing:

```
dt.Columns["Check"].DefaultValue = false;
```

But it isn't really the right thing to do because you're not doing your data access in the right way for datatables based work. Putting this default will allow the grid to show the new row, and then the user can type in it, commit the row etc.. The problem is they don't really have any way of saving this new row (you don't use adapters to write datatable cached data to the database, you do all your data access direct) and you already have a modal dialog that adds new rows so I'm not sure why you want to run your datagridview in AllowUserToAddRows=true mode anyway

A lot of the other code you've written leads me to believe that you regard DataGridView as some sort of container for data, but it's not the design intention - they just show the data they find in something else (DataTable in this case), and you're supposed to manipulate the something_else if you want to manipulate the data, rather than digging it out of the view

Comment: I have added the line in code but giving the same error, When `AllowUserToAddRows` is `true`

Comment: Your all points are correct. I am started working with C# recently and I didn't know how to properly work with that.

Comment: So, what you're saying is you aren't really understanding what I'm saying; you're just trying to find any way of stopping this error. Set `AllowUsertoAddRows = false` then. You don't need it. I made a video demonstrating some techniques for how Microsoft intended this all to work - it takes me about 5 minutes all in to create an app that loads the database data, shows and filters related data, loads a combobox in a datagridview to decode an ID number into a readable name, and save data to the database.. And I didn't write a single line of code: https://youtu.be/zrtjZlTYLQA

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if the data table shows the string false, then you need to change your query to convert false to 0 and true to 1.

```
 private DataTable StudentsDTable()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(DatabaseObjects.ConnectionString))
        {
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT IIf(s.Check = true, 1, 0) AS Check, " +
            "DCount("RollNo","students","RollNo <=" & [RollNo]) AS SrNo, s.RollNo, s.SName, "+ 
            "s.FName, s.DOB, c.Class, s.[Section], s.Picture FROM students AS s LEFT JOIN classes "+ 
            "AS c ON s.ClassID = c.ClassID ORDER BY s.RollNo", conn);
            conn.Open();
            dt.Load(command.ExecuteReader());
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

See [Microsoft Access IIf statement](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/iif-function-32436ecf-c629-48a3-9900-647539c764e3) for IIf.

Let me know please if this works or not.

Sorry, updated my answer so that true = 1 instead of -1. Also changed `\"true\"` to `true`.

Comment: I have tried this query. It shows `0` in the `Check` column bcz all records in database has false value at this time. Error is gone. But No checkboxes now

Comment: What do you have instead of checkbox? Is it just a textbox? Did you manually construct the datagridview in code? You can create the columns manually which gives you more control. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcolumn?view=netframework-4.6.1#examples

Comment: Maybe you can zip up your solution and your Access file and upload it to me? I can take a look at it and let you know what the issue is.

Comment: yes it is just a textbox. I have updated the datatable with value form database. And attach it to the DGV. How can i upload it to you?

Comment: If you have Drop Box or Google Drive or One Drive or something like that, you can put it there and provide the link here. I'm getting ready to go to work, but I will look at it when I get home.

Comment: I am sorry, but I cannot connect to your Access DB to test it. I have Office 365 installed on my machine and it is apparently not compatible with the OleDB provider. I tried different suggestions that I found including uninstalling Office 365 and installing the Office runtime, and that didn't work either. Sorry I couldn't help you.