# Get tables from splitted datatable and run a foreach for every table

Tags: c#, asp.net, foreach, split, datatable

I need to get all tables created when splitting a datatable and the run a foreach onevery row on every table that has been created with the split

This is the code i am using to split the datatable

```
                using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())

            using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(comm))
            {
                adapter.Fill(dt);
                //return dt;

                DataTable[] dt1 = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .Select((row, index) => new { row, index })
                .GroupBy(x => x.index / 9999)  // integer division, the fractional part is truncated
                .Select(g => g.Select(x => x.row).CopyToDataTable())
                .ToArray();

                Foreach (DataSet in dt1){ }
```

Comment: Have you tried iterating over the array of datatables using foreach or for loop? If so, what error or problem did you encounter?

Comment: I cant get the foreach to work, probebly wrong syntax
Need 2 foreach i think, 1 to get all the tables created and 1 to get true all rows in 1 at the time

Comment: Only issue related with foreach? is d1 as you expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over the array of DataTables using `foreach`, and then iterate over the rows of each DataTable using another `foreach`:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        //building the array of DataTables
        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
        DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
        DataTable[] dtArray = new DataTable[2];
        dtArray[0] = dt1;
        dtArray[1] = dt2;
        
        //iterate over array
        foreach(DataTable datatb in dtArray) {
            
            //iterate over rows in individual DataTable
            foreach(DataRow dr in datatb.Rows) {
                 //get column data from row
                 var test = dr["columnName"].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can see how to iterate over columns in each row of a DataTable [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1774498/how-to-iterate-through-a-datatable)